# Media queries (max-width) launch at not specified width

Tags: css, media-queries

[image: screen]

button in the center should be red, when width less than 1024px, but on the image I have width 926px and it is not working. It starts to work only when width becomes less than 922px; I can`t understand why. And how I can correct it?

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
.contacts-page .input-component button {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Without the other css i can't help you. Please provide more CSS. 
If you are using the Developer tools you should see which command overrides your background (a typical failure is to mix background and background-color)

Answer (score 1):

The width for media query is window width.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Perhaps give an example containing the media query?